# MySQL pipelined order by seems not working

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance

I have table 
user[id, name, status] with index[status, name, id]

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE status = 'active'
ORDER BY name, id
LIMIT 50
```

I have about 50000 users with status == 'active'

1.) Why does MySQL explain show about 50000 in ROWS column? Why it follows all leaf nodes even when the index columns equals to order by clause?

2.) When I change order by clause to

```
ORDER BY status, name, id
```

EXTRA column of explain clause shows:

Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort

Is there any reason why it can't use index order in this query?

edit1:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `status_name_id` (`status`,`name`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE status = 'complete'
ORDER BY status, name, id
LIMIT 50
```

explain:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: f_order
type: ref
possible_keys: status_name_id
key: status_name_id
key_len: 768
ref: const
rows: 50331
Extra: "Using where; Using index; Using filesort"
```

The weirdest thing is that if I change SELECT statement to

```
SELECT *, count(id)
```

It use index again and query is twice faster. And extra section contains only

```
Using where; Using index
```

Table contains 100k rows, 5 different statuses and 12 different names.

MySQL: 5.6.27

edit2:

Another example:

This takes 400ms (avg) and does explicit sort

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE status IN('complete')
ORDER BY status, name, id
LIMIT 50
```

This takes 2ms (avg) and doesn't explicit sort

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE status IN('complete', 'something else')
ORDER BY status, name, id
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Inconsistency -- Key `order_status_validation_id` is not in the `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: "5 different statuses" vs "VARCHAR(255) utf8" -- Learn about `ENUM`.

Comment: Oh, I changed column names and I forgot on index name in explain. I know about ENUM, but I think that optimizer should use index for this query. If I had bigger data set, explicit sort can kill my db server.

Comment: `ENUMs` index like `VARCHARs`, but more efficiently because of being smaller.

Comment: "400ms" vs "2ms" -- let's see the `EXPLAINs` for them.

Comment: There is only one difference: 400ms - (Extra: "Using where; Using index; Using filesort"), 2ms - (Extra: "Using where; Using index")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments it is probably bug.

Answer (score 1):

Q1:  `EXPLAIN` is a bit lame.  It fails to take into account the existence of the `LIMIT` when providing the `Rows` estimation.  Be assured that if it can stop short, it will.

Q2:  Did it say that it was using your index?  Please provide the full `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

**More**

With `INDEX(status, name, id)`, the `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, *and* `LIMIT` can be handled in the index.  Hence it has to read only 50 rows.

Without that index, (or with practically any change to the query), much or all of the table would need to be read, stored in a tmp table, sorted, and only then could 50 rows be peeled off.

So, I suggest that it is more complicated than "explicit sort can kill my db server".

Comment: Thank you Rick! That makes absolutely sense. I added table and EXPLAIN query details.

Comment: Yes, but it still does not explain why MySQL explicitly sorts that table. 
Query in my post takes about 400ms avg
If I edit query to this:
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE status = 'complete' OR status = 'non-existent status'
ORDER BY status, name, id
LIMIT 50

it takes 2ms avg

Comment: If there is equation against single value and first index column, first column must not be in order by. If there is 2 or more values in equation, first index column must be in order by. I get it, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I'll report that.